# MySQL large user data storage

Tags: mysql

I want to create a database containing information about which user downloaded which file. Since I have more than 4000 files and number of users is increasing constanly, how can I store so many columns?

Comment: Learn about normalisation.  You would have a record which has the file ID(or name) and the user ID.

Comment: as @NigelRen mentioned, create a table of all users, a table for all files and then have a "user_files" table that links a users id to a file id. data foot print is pretty small

Comment: Its not about normalisation. Even if I normalise I would have to use an array for multiple ID per user or make 4000+ columns for each ID.

Comment: It is about normalisation as it offers standard pattern for many to many relationships

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using "InnoDB, NoSQL with Memcached API". It works really well with both MySQL 5.6 and 5.7. Here is the documentation with the 5.6 version... https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-memcached.html

Comment: Thanks. This is actually helpful.